# Tridion Installation- Installing Outbound Email after HR1 Update

Tags: 2011, configuration

During our first installation process, we did not install few modules such as outbound emails etc and install the Hotfix Rollup #1 as well.

Now we want to run the installer in repair mode to install outbound emails but while running setup it moves directly to last screen with message "Installation completed successfully"

Hope someone knows and may have face similar issue in installing additional module after HR1. Any help or suggestion please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We received similar issue few years ago, when by using DB Manager, we have created the DB for Outbound Email, but did not install it while installing CM.

Can you check on your DB server whether there is any existing DB for outbound email?

If it is rename it/drop it and try again.

Comment: Thanks but it did not help..

Comment: I think it is an ideal question to raise to SDL Support :)